# Is BoUML's State Machine Generator right when it's calling doActivity just before exit from a state of StateMachine?

Tags: uml, state-machine

Consider a simple StateMachine:

[image]

Below is a fragment of C++ code generated by [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/index.html) from it:

```
 // to manage the event create
 void Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::create(Sample & stm) {
         _doentry(stm);
 }

 // perform the 'entry behavior'
 void Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::_doentry(Sample & stm) {
   stm.enter_state1();
 }

 // perform the 'exit behavior'
 void Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::_doexit(Sample & stm) {
   stm.exit_state1();
 }

 // perform the 'do activity'
 void Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::_do(Sample & stm) {
   stm.do_state1();
 }

 // to manage the event exit_state1
 void Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::exit_state1(Sample & stm) {
     _do(stm);
     {
       stm._sample_state._state1_state._doexit(stm);
       stm._set_currentState(stm._sample_state);
       stm._final();
     }
 }
```

Note that `_do(stm)` is called by `Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::exit_state1(Sample & stm)`, i.e. on the exit from State 1, just before the call of the exit behavior `stm._sample_state._state1_state._doexit(stm);`

[The UML Specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) tells us:

> **14.2.3.4.3 State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors**
>
> . . .
>
> A State may also have an associated doActivity Behavior. This Behavior commences execution when the State is entered  (but only after the State entry Behavior has completed) and executes concurrently with any other Behaviors that may be associated with the State, until:
>
> - it completes (in which case a completion event is generated) or
> - the State is exited, in which case execution of the doActivity Behavior is aborted.
>
> The execution of a doActivity Behavior of a State is not affected by the firing of an internal transition of that State.

Wouldn't it be more aligned with UML specification to call `_do(stm)` from `Sample::Sample_State::State1_State::create()`, right after `_doentry(stm);`?

Comment: Your conclusion seems to make sense. Pretty sure Bruno will chip in and comment/answer.

Comment: if you cannot compile your own state machine generator say me on which OS you use BoUML and I will do for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it is worst, I exchanged the management of the *do behavior* between the entry and exit cases. Considering that state machine (the transitions from a state to itself are internal) :
[image]

and the main

```
int main()
{
  MM mm;
  
  mm.create();

  cout << endl << "fire taa" << endl;
  mm.taa();

  cout << endl << "fire tab" << endl;
  mm.tab();

  cout << endl << "fire tbb" << endl;
  mm.tbb();

  cout << endl << "fire tba" << endl;
  mm.tba();

  cout << endl << "fire tdone" << endl;
  mm.tdone();
}
```

Compilation (without defining *VERBOSE_STATE_MACHINE*) and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $ g++ -Wall -g MM.cpp mmain.cpp 
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $ ./a.out
a entry

fire taa
a do
taa

fire tab
a do
a exit
tab expr
b entry

fire tbb
b do
tbb

fire tba
b do
b exit
tba expr
a entry

fire tdone
a do
a exit
tdone
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $
```

So the *do behavior* is executed for an internal transition, wrongly when exiting a state, and is missing when entering in a state.

Note the *state machine* generator is the *plug-out* and its definition is part of BoUML delivery through the project *sm_generator*, it is implemented in C++ (not in Java). So you can load the project *sm_generator*, save-as it where you have the write permission, correct it, generate the C++ code, compile it and replace the official generator with your new version or declare your new *plug-out* and associate it to the *state machine* to have it in the menus.

---

I modified my *state machine generator*, the previous time was in 2011!

The *do behavior* is not anymore executed when exiting the state including through a self external transition, it is  now executed after the possible *do entry*. I also do it after the possible transition behavior of a self internal transition, rather than before, that avoid two consecutive executions without nothing between in case the transition has a behavior.

Note it was already  possible to execute the possible *do behavior* of the current state through the operation *doActivity* defined on the class associated to the machine. That allows to do it between transition firings.

With the previous *state machine* a little modified to add a *self external transition* :

[image]

and that *main*

```
#include "MM.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  MM mm;
  
  mm.create();

  cout << endl << "fire taa" << endl;
  mm.taa();

  cout << endl << "fire ta_a" << endl;
  mm.ta_a();

  cout << endl << "fire tab" << endl;
  mm.tab();

  cout << endl << "fire tbb" << endl;
  mm.tbb();

  cout << endl << "fire tba" << endl;
  mm.tba();

  cout << endl << "fire tdone" << endl;
  mm.tdone();
}
```

Compilation (without defining *VERBOSE_STATE_MACHINE*) and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $ g++ -Wall MM.cpp mmain.cpp 
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $ ./a.out
a entry
a do

fire taa
taa expr
a do

fire ta_a
a exit
ta_a expr
a entry
a do

fire tab
a exit
tab expr
b entry
b do

fire tbb
tbb expr
b do

fire tba
b exit
tba expr
a entry
a do

fire tdone
a exit
tdone expr
pi@raspberrypi:~/sm/src $
```

---

[BoUML 7.10](https://www.bouml.fr/historic.html) is available and fix the problem

Comment: It may be worth mentioning here that on Fedora, for example, the sm_project is in /usr/lib64/bouml/sm_generator/ folder.

Comment: @zer0hedge yes this is where I place them, this is why after loading that project you have to do a save-as else you cannot modify it except being root (or calling *bouml* with *sudo* of course)

Comment: @zer0hedge I modified my *state machine generator* (see edited answer). I do not know when I will distribute a new version of BoUML, I can produce the executable(s) for the OS(s) where you use BoUML to allow you to have it in advance if you want, just ask me.

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate Debian Buster version. I'll migrate to Debian soon.

Comment: @zer0hedge so [install BoUML](https://bouml.fr/download.html#Debian) then replace `/usr/lib/bouml/stmgen` with the new one you can get through `wget http://bouml.fr/buster64/stmgen` md5sum is *3b60357c6974fb2575794aaba8c159e5* and new *state machine generator* version is 5.0.1 (written when you launch it). I suppose you wanted the 64b version rather than the 32b

Comment: BTW you also need to set `stmgen` mode bits execute

Comment: @zer0hedge [BoUML 7.10](https://www.bouml.fr/historic.html) is available containing the new version of the state machine generator