# Composition arrow is too small in Visio

Tags: uml, visio

I am trying to write a small UML diagram in Visio but I noticed the composition arrow is too small by default. Is this a bug or should I configure something before using it?

[image]

Comment: Use a real UML modeling tool, not some painter...

Comment: Do you know a real UML modelling with no fancy colouring and the ability to export vector images?

Comment: Try Enterprise Architect. A bit clumsy in its UI but the best price/value ratio. Can export to emf/wmf (but not svg). You can try it for free for 30 days.

Comment: [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr) is free to use and allows to export diagrams in svg (note I will distribute a new version in the next days to solve [Is BoUML's State Machine Generator right when it's calling doActivity just before exit from a state of StateMachine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629837/is-boumls-state-machine-generator-right-when-its-calling-doactivity-just-befor) and [What is the semantics of UML's ReadVariableAction in BoUML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403771/what-is-the-semantics-of-umls-readvariableaction-in-bouml) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This size is probably dependent on the theme you've selected. Check it on design tab (current "theme"). By default, the size is the same (so "it's just you, not everyone" :D)

[image]